# This question seems too simple, but can't figure out where to begin (about integrals):

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

This question is weird, and it seems too simple, but I feel like I am missing something. The question is as follows:

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, let
$$R = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a \leq x \leq b, y =f(x)  \right\}$$
What I am supposed to show is that the area of $R$ is equal to $0$.

I have no idea where to start however. What I do know from multivariable integrals is I can take a double integral
$\iint\limits_{S} \tilde{f}(x,y)dxdy$ which takes a rectangle around the length $x$ and the function values, and restrict myself to the points which are in $R$. Yet I feel like I am approaching this the wrong way.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: $$\int_a^b\int_{f(x)}^{f(x)}dy\,dx.$$

Comment: That was my idea at first too, but it just felt too simple. Is it really good enough proof?

Comment: @KoenZeven The set $R$ is a line, so it is natural that its area is zero. As for a proof, The suggestion by Yves Daoust does the trick.

Comment: @PierreCarre what if $f$ is a space filling curve? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: @Alan This is not the case... but I should have said "graphic of a function" instead of "line".

Answer (score 1):

If under "area" we understand, for example, [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure), then using fact, that continuous function on compact is uniformly continuous, it's easy to show, that graphic of continuous on segment function has Jordan measure zero.